# Перестановка заданного элемента в конец списка - C++

Tags: c++, списки

Нужно разработать функцию перестановки заданного элемента в конец списка, как это сделать? Третий день ничего не получается

> List.cpp

```
List* LoadList(char* FN, char* LN)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(FN, "rt");

    if (!f)
    {
        cout << " ";
        return NULL;
    }

    char st[Max_ch];
    fgets(st, Max_ch, f);
    List* lst = CreateList(LN, st);

    while (fgets(st, Max_ch, f))
    {
        AddHead(lst, st);
    }

    return lst;
}

// ?????Перестановка?????
void Per(char* Inf)
{
}

/*-Создать элемент списка-*/
Itm* CrItm(int Id, char* Inf)
{
    Itm* t = new Itm;
    t->next = t->prev = NULL;
    t->id = Id;
    strcpy(t->Info, Inf);
    return t;
}

/*-Создать список(Заголовок, информация)-*/
List* CreateList(char* Name, char* Inf)
{
    List* lst = new List;
    strcpy(lst->Name, Name);
    lst->getId = 1;
    lst->begin = CrItm(lst->getId, Inf);
    lst->end = lst->begin;
    return lst;
}

/*-Добавить строку-*/
Itm* AddHead(List* lst, char* Inf)
{
    lst->cur = CrItm(++lst->getId, Inf);
    lst->begin->prev = lst->cur;
    lst->cur->next = lst->begin;
    lst->begin = lst->cur;
    return lst->begin;
}

/*-Вывести список-*/
void ViewLst(List* lst)
{
    printf(" %s \n", lst->Name);
    lst->cur = lst->begin;

    while (lst->cur)
    {
        printf("%i:  %s \n", lst->cur->id, lst->cur->Info);
        lst->cur = lst->cur->next;
    }
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void DelHead(List* lst)
{
    if (lst->begin == lst->end)
    {
        DelLst(lst);
    }
    else
    {
        lst->cur = lst->begin;
        lst->begin->prev = NULL;
        delete lst->cur;
    }
}

void DelLst(List* lst)
{
    while (lst->begin != lst->end)
    {
        DelHead(lst);
    }

    delete lst->begin;
    delete lst;
}

void ViewLstBk(List* lst)
{
    printf(" %s \n", lst->Name);
    lst->cur = lst->end;

    while (lst->cur)
    {
        printf("%i:  %s \n", lst->cur->id, lst->cur->Info);
        lst->cur = lst->cur->prev;
    }
}
```

> List.h

```
 struct Itm
 {
    int id;
    char Info[Max_ch];
    Itm *next, *prev;   //Начало и конец списка
 };

struct List
{
    char Name[20];
    int getId;
    Itm * begin, *cur,*end;
};

List* CreateList(char* Name, char* Inf);
Itm*  AddHead(List* lst, char* Inf);
Itm * CrItm(int id);
void  ViewLst(List* lst);
void  DelHead(List* lst);
void  DelLst(List* lst);
void  ViewLstBk(List* lst);
void  Per(List* lst);
List* LoadList(char* FN, char* LN);
```

Comment: Прототип и реализация функции Per отличаются. Насколько понимаю, должно быть что-то типа void Per(List* lst, char* Inf); Реализуйте функции: поиска по ключу, вырезания, добавления в хвост (могут пригодиться в других задачах). Из них будет состоять функция Per.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да все просто.

```
void Per(List* lst, char* inf)
{
    for(Itm *t = lst->begin; t != NULL; t =  t->next)
    {
        if ((strcmp(t->Info,inf) == 0) && (t != lst->end))
        {
            t->prev->next = t->next;
            t->next->prev = t->prev;
            t->next = NULL;
            t->prev = lst->end;
            t->prev->next = t;
            lst->end = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Только я не исправлял другие ошибки, учтите. Так что у меня, как ит во всем вашем коде, нет проверки на ошибки! А у вас список выводится с конца к началу, считанные из файла строки завершаются на `\n`, еще кое-что по мелочам. Надеюсь, вы справитесь с этими огрехами и допишете проверку на ошибки сами?

И еще - в этом коде нет ничего от C++, кроме отсутствия необходимости везде писать слово `struct` :) Это точно так и надо? Может, лучше тэг на `C` исправить?